# Adding a new column to Spark DataFrame based on lead and lag

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having some issues creating a new column for my Spark DataFrame. To illustrate, I have a table with 3 columns (`features`, `predictions`, `leadCol`). The new column will take the value of column `prediction` if `"prediction" != "leadCol" and if on any row "prediction" === "leadCol"`, the new column should add the average of `prediction` and the previous value in the new column.

Is this possible to do?

I have tried this which is not quite working:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val win_spec = Window.orderBy("features")

// create the new column here with only 1 as value
results = results.withColumn("final_preds", lit(1))

// function to create the new value
def func = when(col("prediction") === col("leadCol"), 
                      ((col("prediction") + lag(col("final_preds"), 1).over(win_spec)) / 2)).otherwise(col("prediction"))

results = results.withColumn("final_preds", func)
```

An example of the faulty output this gives:

[image]

Comment: Based on the logic that you described, the `when` function logic is wrong. "The new column will take the value of column prediction if "prediction" === "leadCol"" ... then it should be: `when(col("prediction") === col("leadCol"), col("prediction")).otherwise(...//logic for "prediction" != "leadCol")`

Comment: @CesarA.Mostacero Sorry my bad, the question was wrong and the logic in my code is the correct one. I'll update my question.